# WordPress filtering custom taxonomies on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I've got two diffrent custom post types sharing the same custom taxonomy. I want the first custom post type to show al the entries from the custom taxonomy. The second custom post type has to filter out one entry and show al other custom taxonomies (based on ID perhaps).

Is this possible? I saw someone suggest using the `post_edit_category_parent_dropdown_args` filter but I don't see how I could use that to actually filter since it doesn't allow for ID's to be specified.

The only other solution I could think of was making another custom taxonomy, copying al the data except for the entry I want to be filtered out but this just seems messy :/

**EDIT**:

Thanks for the responses! I can't share screenshots but I've tried explaining it as best as I can below:

I have two custom post types, one named "vacancy" and another named "order" who share the same custom taxonomy named "location", there are 3 locations defined in the custom taxonomy. Let's say: "Netherlands", "Germany" and "France"

Now I want to be able to select al custom taxonomies when editing "vacancy" so: "Netherlands", "Germany" and "France". When editing "order" I want "Germany" to be hidden or greyed out so the only available options are "Germany" and "France"

Comment: Sorry it is not clear, i have reread first para but seems like it is confusing CPT with Taxonomies and vice versa. Can you please add more details with example of your CPT and taxonomies names to help make it clear?

Comment: Can you show your code for adding your CPT and the taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a solution, we now have 2 custom taxonomy for the "location" taxonomy. :(